# How to solve "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified" exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have several stored procedures for updating different tables. And when I execute them I get the exception as follows

> Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified

I tried answers found on over the internet but couldn't fix it.
Here is my code for one stored procedure

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "update_HS_HR_EMP_BANK_AADM";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@appNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = appNo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BRANCH_CODE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = branch;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACCOUNTNO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = account;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ACCOUNT_TYPE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = type;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

This is my stored procedure

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_HS_HR_EMP_BANK_AADM] 
        @appNo int,
        @BRANCH_CODE VARCHAR(10),
        @ACCOUNTNO VARCHAR(50),
        @ACCOUNT_TYPE VARCHAR(1)        

    AS
    BEGIN

        Update [HS_HR_EMP_BANK_AADM]
        SET
            [BBRANCH_CODE]=@BRANCH_CODE
            ,[EBANK_ACC_NO]=@ACCOUNTNO
            ,[EBANK_ACC_TYPE_FLG]=@ACCOUNT_TYPE
            ,[EBANK_ACTIVE_FLAG]=1
            ,[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE]=GETDATE()
        Where App_no=@appNo
    END
```

Comment: call this `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` before adding parameters and also try to drop recreate procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things that you should try to investigate

Check the **connection string** to check it is hitting the right database

Try specifying the command type :

```
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

And change the parameter type you are passing in for the appNo from Varchar to Int.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@appNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = appNo;
```

As per the stored proc, it should be int.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@appNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = appNo;
```

Comment: Notable thing, but that specified error is not because of this

Comment: @ Ash there is no error  as I can see. I changed the varchar to int

Answer (score 0):

Your passing parameter type did not matched. `@appNo` add as a `varchar` but it is `int` in procedure.

change this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@appNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = appNo;
```

To this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@appNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = appNo;
```